# How to send results in json object from controller to page?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

currently in my spring mvc project i am returning a modelmap to index page. now **i don't want to use modelmap to send data**. i want to use **json object** to send data to page. and display the data using json deocode or like that. i dont know very much about json.

**i dont have any problem if u remove jstl and use something else if that is needed for json printing**

**controller**

```
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
        srs = jt.queryForRowSet(sql);
        while (srs.next()) {
            pojo obj = new pojo();
            obj.setId(srs.getString("id"));
            obj.setFullname(srs.getString("full_name"));
            obj.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));
            arraylist.add(obj);
        }
        modelMap.put("list", arraylist);
    return "index";
```

**index page**

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({url: "fetch.htm",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    context: document.body,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(search), 
                    success: function (result) {

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Why would you pass an object as JSON, to then be forced to parse the JSON to an object and display the contents of that object? Why not pass the object directly? Or are you asking how to make an AJAX request from your page, that would return JSON, that JavaScript code would then use to modify the DOM of the HTML page?

Comment: actually i want to use json to send bulk data from controller to page and display using json, So, i want any sort of help regarding this. i am very new to json. i will make ajax request to get json data. controller should send json data. i just simply want ------- ** querying database in sprinh mvc, returning result using json **

Comment: Again, what's the point? If you have a List of objects in memory, why would you, instead of just passing a reference to that list to your JSP, serialize the whole list to JSON, pass the JSON to the JSP, and then deserialize the JSON to be able to print its content? That's wasteful, and doesn't have any advantage over just passing the list directly. JSON is useful when you need to transfer information over the network. Not to pass objects between Java objects in the same application. You wouldn't send a letter to your brother to tell him something if he's in the same room as you, would you?

Comment: @JBNizet hahahah .... ohh got it .. JUST tell me one thing ,, is this like that ,, --- using modelmap and arraylist for sending bulk data will give load to server. and using json to send bulk data will not give load to server because it will run in client. ------ i just mean that >> i dont want to give any load to server, i want server to run smoothly. i will give load to client software.

Comment: It's not about load, it's about application architecture. In both cases you need to get the data from the database, and transform them (to HTML, or to JSON). If you want to send JSON to the browser, you need the browser to send an AJAX request, get the JSON back, and use JavaScript to update the DOM.

Comment: ok... thanks , i am adding ajax request.

Comment: check my edited code .. i have added ajax request onload body. so,, now hoe to send data from controller to that json script and display.

Comment: You annotate your Spring controller method with `@ResponseBody`, return the List<Pojo> from that method, and make sure you have Jackson in the classpath, as documented. Also, don't map the method to fetch.htm, since it doesn't return html, but JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your data in `json` format as shown below:

**Code:**

```
return Json(new { success = true, message = "message", aaData = arraylist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: didnt get it ,, please help with code ... i told earlier,, i do not know json programming. please edit my controller with json.

Comment: sorry,, with just a line of code.. i can not do anything,,, i can find it anywhere on internet,, but how to embed it ,, impliment it

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonObject and jsonArray as shown below

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray somearr = new JSONArray();
                        while (iter.hasnext()) {
                             ClassName someObject=iter.next();
                            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                            jsonobj.put("id", id_from_someObject);;
                            jsonobj.put("name", name_from_someObject);
                            somearr.put(seatObj);

                        }

mainObj.put("response",somearr);

return mainObj.toString();
```